# Spring Riak Integration

Tags: java, spring, riak, nosql

I want to integrate Riak with my Spring application. I looked at Spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/riak.html) and found they have a module called spring-data-keyvalue. This module supports key value databases. When I looked at [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-keyvalue) of this module I am not able to find Riak related classes like RiakTemplate etc.
Can someone guide me to figure out dependency for Riak.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Riak is currently not supported as much as Redis in Spring Data unfortunately.

I found two repositories which you might find useful:

An example Spring Boot app using the Riak Java client written by Jon Brisbin (former Pivotal employee)
https://github.com/jbrisbin/tfl-ingest

Another one is an old repository when Costin Leau was still working at Pivotal:
https://github.com/ericturcotte/spring-data-keyvalue/

If you need only a key value store, use Redis. It has excellent Spring Data support, even who wrote the *lettuce* (Redis java driver) works for Pivotal.

Hope it helps.